# Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function - Apollo client -Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql

I am building a project management application using reactjs and graphql.

When I send out query from reactjs it gets a response with the data below

```
{
   "data":{
    "clients":[
       {
         "name":"Okoye Ifeoma",
         "email":"ify@mail.com",
         "phone":"0805-854-754-580"
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

But it does not show the data on the browser instead it display the following error on the console

*Error: Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function*

Clients

```
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import ClientRow from "./ClientRow";
const GET_CLIENTS = gql`
  query getClients {
    clients {
      id
      name
      email
      phone
    }
  }
`;

export const Clients = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CLIENTS);

  if (loading) return <p>loading...</p>
  console.log(data.clients);
  if (error) return <p>Something went wrong</p>
  return (
    <>
      {!loading && !error && (
        <table className="table table-hover mt-3">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.clients.map(client => {
              <ClientRow key={client.id} client={client} />
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

ClientRow

```
import { FaTrash } from "react-icons/fa";
export default function ClientRow({ client }) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{client.name}</td>
      <td>{client.email}</td>
      <td>{client.phone}</td>
      <td>
        <button className="btn btn-danger">{FaTrash}</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

Comment: In this case Etranz *is* using the array. When given an array of Components, React will just render each Component in the array, at that position.

Comment: Just remove the brackets: `client => <ClientRow key={client.id} client={client} />`. The return value is implicit in arrow functions. Unless you use brackets, in which case you have to specify an explicit `return` value. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's gone wrong?

The arrow function in Clients > tbody is not returning anything.

```
{
  data.clients.map(
    client => { <ClientRow key={client.id} client={client} /> }
  )
}
```

When you enclose the body of an arrow function in {}s you must expressly `return` a value.

## The Fix

Simply enclose your JSX in parenthesis and return it from the function.

```
{
  data.clients.map(
    client => { return (
      <ClientRow key={client.id} client={client} /> 
    )}
  )
}
```

Comment: Worked like magic. Thanks

Comment: That's unnecessarily verbose. `data.clients.map( client => <ClientRow key={client.id} client={client} /> )` does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not interested in graphql, but you can check if data is fetched or not.

```
data && data.clients.map(client => {.....})
```